# wp_mail line break not working

Tags: wp-mail

I have an interface to send e-mails through `SMTP` (I use the plug-in `Postman SMTP`).

I collect messages in the DB that I sent to someone depending on the results of an SQL request.

In the DB, I stored the messages using the char `&#13;` for line breaks.

Here is the code (I replace e-mail addresses with xxx, but obviously I use my client's e-mail address in the real piece) :

```
$subject = $res->subject;
$message = utf8_encode( $msg );

$to = $res->url ;
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: XXX <xxx@xxx.com>' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: xxx@xxx.com' . "\r\n";         

$sent = wp_mail($to, $subject , $message , $headers);
```

Everything works (I receive the right e-mail with proper encoding), however everything is sent on a single line (when there should be a line break each time there is a `&#13;` in the database message).
Oddly, there are no  in the e-mail, they are just deleted from the message.

I also tried to add the following lines (on separate tests, obviously) :

```
$message = str_replace('&#13;', "\r\n", $message);
$message = str_replace('&#13;', '<br />', $message);
```

But I get the same results.

Could you please help me sort this out ?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the line that reads `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";` to `$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";` and then use `<br />` for the line breaks.